# Facebook request from Https to Http through cUrl

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook, curl, https

On October 1st, a secure Url will be mandatory on facebook apps.
Now, what I want to do is create a registration form in an iframe (php) on facebook, which does a cUrl post to an external .aspx page, which handles the parameters and inserts in the database.

At this point, this works. Now my question is, since we will be having an SSL certificate within a week or so, so the app can be hosted on a secure environment, will facebook block my cUrl post to the external (non-https) page? Sorry for the silly question, I'm a cUrl noob.

I have an other question, if everything's okay, and facebook doesn't block my cUrl post, how do I send something back from the ASP.NET page and catch it on the php page?

So in short, I have to post some parameters from a php handler to a .net page, which inserts into the db and returns a number (for instance; 0=success, 1=fail).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl transaction happens on the backend which should not be a visible transaction to FB so you should be alright.

For the response you should be able to get that in the curl response.  Below is a sample curl request that grabs a response.  Your curl settings will probably be different so this is merely provided as an example to start from.

```
   function testcurl(){
    $url="http://www.somehost.com/";

    $fields = array('DWStatus'=>$object['object']);
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value):
         $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    endforeach;

    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $response  = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response; }
```

Comment: thank you very much, I've managed to get a response from the .net page, in a similar way like yours. Your first sentence confirms what I was thinking, thanks again!